# Spring BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: sql, spring, oracle

I run my program and get the following exception:

```
Class: oracle.retail.stores.foundation.manager.data.DataException
(Revision $Revision: /main/18 $) @896499272: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT myschema.MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL]; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Transaction Name:                   [TransactionWriteDataTransaction]
Error code:                         [0] [An unknown exception occurred.]
Error code (extended):              [0]
Description:                        [org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT myschema.MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL]; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist]
```

Running `SELECT myschema.MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL` in SQL developer returns a record so I don't understand why exception is  `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: Resolved, `MY_SEQ` belongs to `myschema` but my app uses `myschema_user` to connect DB, `myschema_user` does not have permission on `myschema.MY_SEQ`.